# How can I stop instagram from pushing notifications when it shouldn't have internet access

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I've turned off mobile data for instagram in settings.

I cannot use the app when I am on data, because it has no internet access.

However, it will still create new red bubbles on the home screen... it is receiving notifications even though I don't want it to. How can I stop this, and the same behaviour for similar apps?

Comment: iPad? iPhone? If you have an iPad, does it have cellular access?

Comment: @IconDaemon iphone

Comment: Is your iPhone connected to WiFi?

Comment: @IconDaemon no.

Comment: I would assume that the mobile data setting for an app only controls outbound traffic (traffic initiated by the app), it doesn‘t stop push notifications from coming in.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly here? Disable push notifications? Disable notification badges (aka "red bubbles on the Home Screen")?

Comment: Have you tried going to *Settings > Notifications > Instagram* and disabling notifications? There is also an option called "Badges", you can disable this to avoid having "red bubbles" on the Home Screen. :)

Comment: Notifications come from Apple servers, not from the app polling to see if there are any.